# Wordpress single page product and checkout

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to woocommerce and trying to combine the single product page and checkout page together. For eg: I want to move the billing details from this page

https://exthemes.net/wootour/checkout/

to

https://exthemes.net/wootour/product/new-york-philadelphia-washington/

How can I achieve this?

From my research there is only a premium plugin from woocommerce which provides this functionality which is not an option and [woocommerce_checkout] shows checkout page on product page. I need to move the billing form from checout page to product page

Please provide pointers or free plugins if available on how to achieve this.

Comment: You need to create your own custom template if you don't want to use any additional plugins

Answer (score 0):

1. First create child theme
2. Check the code of `form-checkout.php` and place it on products page.
3. You can see `form-billing.php` and `form-shipping.php` codes. You can add this your products page
4. Note: Woocommerce templates can be [overridden](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) in your child themes

Comment: [woocommerce_checkout] only works if any product is available in the cart. I dont want the whole checkout page. I want each product page to have billing form.

Comment: I tried that. But it seems it works only if there is any product in cart. Please see the below link https://www.holiday-factory.com/crazydeals/lebanon. This is similar to what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found is to empty cart and add product to cart when visiting a single product page from a specific category. I also added the checkout form on my single product page using the plugin Woocommerce Single Page Checkout.

```
/**
 * @snippet       Add Product to Cart When Visiting a Single Product Page from a Specific Category - WooCommerce
 * @author        Zaa Normandin
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @compatible    WooCommerce 3.4.3
 */

add_action( 'wp', 'bbloomer_add_product_to_cart_on_page_id_load' );

function bbloomer_add_product_to_cart_on_page_id_load() {

   // first, bail if WC isn't active since we're hooked into a general WP hook
    if ( ! function_exists( 'WC' ) ) {
        return; 
    }


    $id = get_the_ID();


    if (is_product() && has_term( 'information', 'product_cat' ) || is_product_category( 'information' )) {
      WC()->cart->empty_cart();
      WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $id ); 
    } 
}
```

Ref.: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-product-to-cart-when-visiting-a-specific-page/

I added the code at the end of functions.php